# How to VLOOKUP one value out from a cell with multiple values separated by comma?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

How to VLOOKUP one value out from a cell with multiple values separated by comma?

For example, I am trying to get the Project ID of the SKU in C2. However, in A:A, there are multiple values in a cell which are separated by a comma. A simple VLOOKUP won't work.

[image: VALUES]

Comment: Are the project ID's only numeric? I.e. will you ever need to return that `N/A` in `B6`?

Comment: @BigBen ProjectIDs are only numeric. Forgive me for the N/A. I will delete the N/As

Comment: Are they actual numbers too? They are left aligned which makes me think they're text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Project IDs are numeric and are true numbers, then use `SUMIF` with wildcards:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,"*"&C2&"*",B:B)
```

If the project IDs aren't necessarily numeric, you could use an approach like the following:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$14,SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C2,$A$2:$A$14))*ROW($A$1:$A$13)))
```

[image]

Comment: SUMIF accepts wildcards, so it can "look-up" the corresponding numeric value against the text in column A. It's really a sum, but can be used in instances like this, where the return value is numeric.

Comment: Possible issues: no match, or the corresponding project ID is *text-that-looks-like-a-number*.

Comment: Now I know why. There are some cells within the project ID that has multiple values like "470211, 470212". It cannot look it up because there are two numbers separated by a comma. Is that correct?

Comment: Right, SUMIF can't return text. I added an alternate approach.

Answer (score 1):

Or, try this :

```
=LOOKUP(1,-SEARCH(C2,A$2:A$21),B$2:B$21)
```